# Remove CodeBlocks and know file path

Tags: software-recommendation, gnome-terminal, software-sources, code-blocks

I had installed the code block earlier, Now I want to remove it and shift to IDE (recommendation are welcome, specially c/c++) but through the terminal

> "Package 'codeblocks' is not installed, so not removed"

and in ubuntu software, no software present as named codeblocks but I can see codeblocks in the application manager, I also tried to find the file through the file manager didn't get success.
[image showing codeblocks in application manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiiNC.jpg)

As told @N0rbert  in comment `which codeblocks` command output:

```
/usr/local/bin/codeblocks
```

Comment: Please add output of `which codeblocks` to the question. It may be installed with non-APT way.

Comment: Added, So bin/codeblocks directory where all set up present ?

Comment: So it was installed as binary to `/usr/local/` by some binary installer. Do you remember how it was installed?

Comment: No, around one or two years ago I did it.

Comment: What is the version of CodeBlocks? Theoretically we can download the same binary installer for it and then run un-uninstaller from it. Are you sure that it was binary installation (not source-based self-compiled one)?

Comment: version: SVN build rev 11542. I am not sure about binary installation but I think it was since it is not removed codeblock through terminal, this case may arise only when binary installation happened. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have compiled **CodeBlocks** previously  in somewhere (for example in *~/Downloads/codeblocks...*) and then installed with `make install` to the `/usr/local`.

If you can find this location, then use `sudo make uninstall` from this directory.

If you can not find this location - then situation is some-kind of worse.
You can try to move executable and its desktop-file with commands below:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/local/bin/codeblocks
sudo mv /usr/local/share/applications/codeblocks*.desktop /usr/local/
```

and forget about the CodeBlocks :)

---

About **alternatives** - I'll highly recommend to try KDevelop. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install kdevelop
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked. Recently trying sublime, definitely, I will try kdevelop. Thanks for suggestion. Wanna upvote but repos<15.